# Couchbase threads are in BLOCKED state

Tags: java, couchbase

We are doing the load testing of our application , which uses the Couchbase DB.
We are taking the thread dumps at regular intervals. In all the thread dumps after making call to couchbase threads are in BLOCKED state.
We are not understating this behaviour

Below is the configuration of couchbase environment

```
  DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().kvTimeout(5000).connectTimeout(7500)
                .viewTimeout(7500).queryTimeout(7500).disconnectTimeout(10000)
                .retryStrategy(BestEffortRetryStrategy.INSTANCE).build();
```

And we are doing simple CRUD oerations over like

```
                JsonDocument doc =
                        JsonDocument.create("1236",
                                JsonObject.create().put("name", "test"));
bucket.insert(doc);
```

Below is the stackstrace what we obtained from Jstack

```
Thread 4257: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) @bci=139, line=1037 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) @bci=25, line=1328 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=10, line=277 (Compiled frame)
 - com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(rx.Observable, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=32, line=72 (Compiled frame)
 - com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.get(java.lang.String, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=17, line=118 (Compiled frame)
 - com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.get(java.lang.String) @bci=9, line=113 (Compiled frame)
```

All our documents are in KBs.
We have a cluster with 3 nodes.
Java sdk version- 2.3.4

Please guide us in understanding the behaviour.

Thanks

Comment: I'm no expert, but the method name `blockForSingle()` sounds like CouchBase is trying to serialize all threads for some reason (index rebuilding?).  I'd show that stack trace to the folks on the CouchBase mailing list/forum and ask them what it means.  You might get more knowledgeable folks who know CouchBase internals.

Comment: I posted the same question in couchbase forum also

Answer (score 0):

I got the proper explanation and solution for the above question what I have posted.

Reason for BLOCKED states of the threads is the usage of synchronus operation.

Instead of using

```
bucket.insert
```

we used async operation provided in couchbase JAVA SDK as

```
Observable.just(metaId).flatMap(docId -> 
    bucket.async()                             
    .upsert(JsonDocument.create(metaId, JsonObject.fromJson(docContent))))
    .toBlocking()
    .singleOrDefault(null);
```

This helped us to get better throughput and we are not seeing the threads in BLOCKED state and also application TPS is increased to very good value.

Below is thread of the couchbase forum discussion for the above question

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-threads-are-in-blocked-state/11524/2

Hope this will be helpful.